# Images are not showing on localhost. What settings do I need to change?

Tags: 8, media

My images are not showing. I have looked this question up but all of the solutions I found were over a year old and my settings.php file does not have a $base_url setting.

If you try to view an image with the browser, you can see it at localhost/mysite/sites/default/files/image.jpg, but Drupal is pointing to
localhost/sites/default/files/image.jpg and the subdirectory is being left out.

How do I fix this?

I am using Drupal 8 on LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I copied the sites folder for that drupal installation and pasted it in the /var/www/ directory and I now  see the image. But, this is just a temporary fix and I bet there is a config setting I can change so that I do not need to copy and paste the sites folder outside of the drupal folder.

Comment: Your problem is caused from having an unusual root. It can be easily avoided if you used virtual hosts. Is there a reason you are not using virtual hosts?